# How to remove id with double colon via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to remove an id with double colon?

```
<li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="Vendor_Name::users_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="Vendor_Name::users" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">
```

What I tried:

```
$('[id*="Vendor_Name::users"]').remove();
$("#Vendor_Name\\:\\:users").remove();
$(document.getElementById("Vendor_Name::users")).remove();
$('li[id*="Vendor_Name::users"]').remove();
$('[id="Vendor_Name::users"]').remove();
$("li#Vendor_Name\\:\\:users").remove();
```

**Nothing works.**
Removing other elements are working, so it has to do with ::

I can remove it via CSS, though, but I want to remove the element completely from DOM.

```
#Vendor_Name\:\:users {
  display: none;
}
```

EDIT: Got it working with MutationObserver. In case anybody needs it:

```
const DEL_SELECTOR = '#Vendor_Name\\:\\:users';

            const mo = new MutationObserver(onMutation);
// in case the content script was injected after the page is partially loaded
            onMutation([{addedNodes: [document.documentElement]}]);
            observe();

            function onMutation(mutations) {
                const toRemove = [];
                for (const {addedNodes} of mutations) {
                    for (const n of addedNodes) {
                        if (n.tagName) {
                            if (n.matches(DEL_SELECTOR)) {
                                toRemove.push(n);
                            } else if (n.firstElementChild && n.querySelector(DEL_SELECTOR)) {
                                toRemove.push(...n.querySelectorAll(DEL_SELECTOR));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (toRemove.length) {
                    mo.disconnect();
                    for (const el of toRemove) el.remove();
                    observe();
                }
            }

            function observe() {
                mo.observe(document, {
                    subtree: true,
                    childList: true,
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use [`jQuery.escapeSelector`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) and then remove the element.

> which Escapes any character that has a special meaning in a CSS
> selector.

```js
const escapedSelector = $.escapeSelector("Vendor_Name::users");
console.info(escapedSelector); // Vendor_Name\:\:users

$('#' + escapedSelector).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Test paragraph before list</p>
<li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="Vendor_Name::users_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="Vendor_Name::users" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">Test list
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

note: That this method was added in jQuery version 3.

**Solution for older version of jQuery:** source taken from the [jQuery core FAQ section](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)

```js
function jq( myid ) {
  return "#" + myid.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=|@)/g, "\\$1" );
}
console.info(jq('Vendor_Name::users')) // #Vendor_Name\:\:users
$(jq('Vendor_Name::users')).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Test paragraph before list</p>
<li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="Vendor_Name::users_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="Vendor_Name::users" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">Test list
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Gives "Uncaught TypeError: $.escapeSelector is not a function" unfortunately. I'm using Magento 2, so it could be because of older version of JQuery?

Comment: @hardy123480 That is true. Just added a solution for older jQuery versions, check it out if that works for you.

Comment: No error anymore but it does still not remove the element. info is: #Vendor_Name\:\:users so it should actually work. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Is the dom getting dynamically painted after this code runs or something. Could you check if `console.log($(jq('Vendor_Name::users')))` gives you the element?

Comment: Yes, it gives: selector: "#Vendor_Name\\:users"

Comment: Check the length as I did in my test `$(selector)` always returns an object regardless of match found or not so long as the selector expression doesn't throw an internal selector parsing error

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the following test of every example you gave that they are all valid and all find the element...assuming it exists when you run it.

The `js-tree` class indicates this is probably a tree plugin that uses an internal state to render various nodes. You probably want to use the API of the plugin to do what is needed

```js
const selectors = [
    '[id*="Vendor_Name::users"]',
    "#Vendor_Name\\:\\:users",
    document.getElementById("Vendor_Name::users"),
    'li[id*="Vendor_Name::users"]',
    "li#Vendor_Name\\:\\:users"
]

const allValid = selectors.every(s=> $(s).length > 0)
console.log('allValid =', allValid)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="Vendor_Name::users" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Getting "allValid = false" actually, even if I test every single selector.

Comment: So the difference is my demo runs when we know  the element exists. Yours indicates it doesn't exist when you run that code. Js Tree will insert elements in the dom dynamically

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why. I tried to remove the class "jstree-node" which works fine.

Comment: You are dealing with a robust stateful plugin that can render elements dynamically. As mentioned in my answer you probably need to use the plugin api to do what you need. Not 100% sure but think it is https://www.jstree.com/

Comment: There is one other more complex alternative and that is using a MutationObserver

Comment: One more alternative is intercept the data passed to the plugin and alter it before the plugin initializes

Comment: MutationObserver works. Edited above. Pretty sure it could be improved, but anyway. Thanks.